# Proper use of formSubmitReply

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a problem with a function that uses trigger formSubmitReply. I created this script to be able to receive notifications of the form that was filled, but when I get the email with the information, I received the email from my account. Is it possible that the script sends the email on behalf of the person who is filling out the form?

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/execution_container_triggers), **Container-specific installable triggers execute under the identity of the user who created the trigger.**

the onFormSubmit trigger is one of these, so this is normal behavior.

If you are using a googleApps account you can get the identity of the user filling the form, a warning will be shown in the form itself, but the mail itself will still be sent with your account

Another alternative would be to create your form using UiApp and run the webapp as 'the user accessing the App', then the email would be sent by the user's account, this webapp will ask for authorization before executing.

Comment: Yes, that's what I had in mind, but I am not that experienced to be able to create the UiApp to look like the form I made. I'll try it though, Thank you @Serge